# Too high screen resolution - cause damage?

Tags: resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does increasing “Screen refresh rate” damage monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/80843/does-increasing-screen-refresh-rate-damage-monitors)

I accidentally put the resolution of my screen to high and it caused my graphics driver to crash and had to reinstall my external display's driver again.

I wondered if putting the resolution too high can cause physical damage to the screen?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/80843/does-increasing-screen-refresh-rate-damage-monitors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not the resolution but the refresh rate (if set too high) can cause damage to the display.

Comment: Though, with some CRTs, you should watch out because the acceptable refresh rate goes down when you raise the resolution. For example, I have a display which can do 120hz at 320x240, but only 60hz at 1280x960. Technically, the limiting factor is the pixel clock, the number of pixels actually refreshed per second.

Answer (score 5):

To a CRT, possibly.  To an LCD, not as far as I've ever heard.

Edit: Broam and Molly are absolutely correct, inappropriate refresh rate is what can pop a CRT, not resolution (`call to fork() failed`).  Still, AFAIK, neither will do anything to an LCD.

Comment: Older CRT monitors could be damaged by a high refresh rate. More recent ones would have detect "out of range" refresh rates and refuse to display an image.

Comment: and it wasn't just *high* refresh rates that could damage them; it was *any* refresh rates that the monitor wasn't designed for.

Comment: Since refresh/resolution are just different variables in the same function, excessive resolution may result in an excessive refresh rate on a CRT, hence causing failure.  So it's both right and wrong to say that refresh rate is all that matters.  ;-)  You could get away with higher than spec resolutions if the video card let you drop the refresh down low enough in some cases (43hz anyone? :-) ).  As mentioned above too, LCDs are pretty much impervious.  I've never run across one that you could push out of range.